# Is there a way for git to checksum a repository for sanity?

Tags: git

I just pulled an old bare repository from a server that has suffered from filesystem corruption.

Does git have any mechanisms for sanity checking the the bare repository for corrupted blobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [git fsck](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) command, which "Verifies the connectivity and validity of the objects in the database".